# how to apply an image to background of a folder

Tags: windows-xp

I want to apply an image to the background of a folder.

How can I do this in Windows XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/10/16/folder-background-images-in-winxp/) a tutorial:

1. Turn on "Show hidden files and folders" in "Tools" - "Folder Options"
2. Right click in the folder, open "Properties"
3. Go to "Customize" - "Change Icon" and select any icon
4. Open the newly created "Desktop.ini" file with a text editor
5. Paste the following:

`[ExtShellFolderViews]`

`{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}={BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}`

`[{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}]`

`IconArea_Image=C:\yourfile.bmp`

Then change the path to the image to your image.

Comment: Embedded the content, sry bout that.

Comment: Nice. (I was tempted to edit your answer to replace the backticks with a code block by either using `<pre>` or an indentation of 4 spaces. But given the length of the 2nd line, maybe on a Windows machine that would show a horizontal scrollbar?)

Comment: Yeah, I had problems with that too, so I figured that worked best.